# Performance Entity framework 6 startup and update

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading, entity-framework-6

Im using lazyloading and pre generated views. 
I create the context. 
I get all my objects about 6000 + navigations are filled in like 3sec. thats ok. 
I update all my objects first time ( 4mins....) 
I update all my objects second time ( 6sec )

I suspect lazyloading running on background and updating must be doing something that makes him reloop or EF startup is still loading..

I'm on EF 6.1 and the datas are hierarchical.

Database size is about 6000rows on 30 tables.

EF model is DatabaseFirst.

Any Workaround ?

Comment: What is the issue? Are concerned about the performance difference between the 1st and 2nd updates? Your question isn't clear about what it is that you're looking for a "workaround" for.

Comment: I mean the problem is I open my program and I do 6000 updates before entities are fully loaded. it takes 4min. I update after with an other value. it takes 6sec. loading is a major problem for me

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is about the time difference between the two updates, I suspect that the second one runs faster because fewer objects have been modified.

Comment: Same loop twice, I update 2 different integers of the entity.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need all the objects loaded into your context? What is the lifecycle of your context?

The general recommendation is that you create single use contexts - for a single web request or a single windows form.

You'll further see a lot of example with a using statement, where the life of the context is purposely kept very short.  Letting the context live too long can increase memory usage and increase the possibility of concurrency problems.  Your database and other layers also do their own caching.

Lastly, Lazy loading is fine, as long as you don't know if you're going to need things.  You can consider explicitly loading data if you know you're going to need related records, and want to avoid multiple round trips.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: With eagerloading I still have the same bad performance... I mean its only happening on startup. I can see when I debug that my entities in my context are still loading up.